# Temporary tables in SSIS package taking a long time to load

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I have an SSIS package which is connecting to Oracle Source. I have created a temporary table which is being used by the main query withing the package. But its is taking a long time to run the package as its running the whole query in the temporary table. I need to run it every hour for updates. Can anyone suggest any solutions? Thanks.

Below is the query used :

```
with t as 
(
select PI.INFO_TYPE_CD
      ,PI.INFO_SUB_TYPE_CD
      ,PI.VALUE_CD
      ,pi.VALUE_NUMERIC
      ,pi.person_id
      ,ph.phone_num

from person_info pi

join person_info pi2 on pi.person_id = pi2.person_id
                and pi2.info_sub_type_cd = 82.00 and pi2.value_cd = 194.00

join phone ph on ph.parent_entity_id = pi.person_id
         and ph.phone_type_cd = 38.00 and ph.active_ind = 1

where pi.info_sub_type_cd =     1.00 and pi.value_cd = 19.00
)


SELECT  
 ppr.RELATED_PERSON_ID
 ,ph.phone_num
 ,case 
  when ph.PHONE_NUM is NULL
    then t.phone_num
  else
     ph.phone_num
  end as phone

FROM
    person_reltn   ppr

join phone ph on ph.PARENT_ENTITY_ID = ppr.PERSON_ID
             and ph.phone_type_cd = 38.00 and ph.active_ind = 1

left outer join t on t.person_id = ppr.RELATED_PERSON_ID

where ppr.updt_dt_tm >= "some date"
```

Comment: Check for indexes and if it is a temp table issue, convert it to a permanent table

Comment: Hi Brad, I cannot convert temp to permanent table as the source cannot be modified. Are you suggesting me to create a permanent table in my SQL Server DB and then link that back to Oracle ?